# "Close all" does not always close all

Tags: android, operating-system

I have noticed something peculiar regarding the "Close all" option, that appear when you press the three horizontal lines in the lower left corner:

Often, all visible apps slide upwards, and everything close as it should.

But sometimes all apps slide sideways off the screen, always to the left, and disappear. However, none of them are closed down, and reappear when pressing the three lines again.

Can anyone recognize this behavior, and explain what happens and why?

This is a Samsung A21s, Android version 12.